# Turning list into dictionary where list value is dict key and value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list with long strings in it, a number and then a ‘sentence’ let’s say. I was wondering if there was a way to turn this into a dictionary, with the number being the value

```
mylist = ['8 red cars', '3 blue cars', '11 black cars']
```

That is my list and I want the dictionary to be:

```
{
 'red cars': 8
 'blue cars': 3
 'black cars': 11
}
```

Comment: Did you try to write any code for this? For example, what do you imagine are the logical steps in the process? Can you write code for each step?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turning list into dictionary where list value is both dict key and value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65042445/turning-list-into-dictionary-where-list-value-is-both-dict-key-and-value)

Comment: @NikolaosChatzis Interesting... that question is the exact same question... asked by the same person, about an hour ago... and getting it closed as a duplicate.

Comment: On further investigation, it looks like actually OP edited that question from a previous one, to make it this one... and then re-asked it... weird. OP, please don't do that. I rolled back the edit on the other question.

Comment: Hi, sorry my original question was something different and it was closed as someone found a similar question, so I just thought i could edit it to a new question! Apologies

Answer (score 1):

All previous approaches are completely valid, but I am going to put my two cents in:

```py
d = {}
for x in ['8 red cars', '3 blue cars', '11 black cars']:
    [k, v] = x.split(' ', 1) # ['8', 'red cars']
    d[int(k)] = v

print(d) # {8: 'red cars', 3: 'blue cars', 11: 'black cars'}
```

## Update

Apparently you have updated your question, so here is the corresponding answer:

```py
d = {}
for x in ['8 red cars', '3 blue cars', '11 black cars']:
    [k, v] = x.split(' ', 1) # ['8', 'red cars']
    d[v] = int(k)

print(d) # {'red cars': 8, 'blue cars': 3, 'black cars': 11}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is a better way, but the code below works for your example.

```
mylist = ['8 red cars', '3 blue cars', '11 black cars']
car_dict = {}

for item in mylist:
    number = [int(s) for s in item.split() if s.isdigit()][0]
    words = [str(s) for s in item.split() if s.isalpha()]
    car_dict[number] = ' '.join(words)
    
print(car_dict)
```

Comment: Thank you, but i extended my list to : mylist = ['8 red cars', '3 blue cars', '11 black cars', '1 yellow car', '1 silver car', '22 blue vans', '11 green cars', '11 black vans', '4 white cars'], but the output is only: {8: 'redcars', 3: 'bluecars', 11: 'blackvans', 1: 'silvercar', 22: 'bluevans', 4: 'whitecars'}

Comment: This is due to the nature of dictionaries in python. All keys must be unique. Since the numbered 11 comes up twice, the first value will get overwritten by the second one. It is up to you how you want to deal with that but you can not have 2 identical keys in a dictionary. You can save the values to a ```list``` for a example. So ```{11: ['black vans', 'black cars`]}``` and so on

Comment: Ah yes of course? In that case would it work if I made the numbers the value and the ‘red car’ (for example) as the key?

Comment: Yes that should certainly work if description of the cars are all unique. So just have ```car_dict['  '.join(words)] = number``` instead of the line you have now.

Answer (score 0):

**[EDIT]:** As the question is Edited. (Reverse the KEY, VALUE emplacement)

```
mylist = ['8 red cars', '3 blue cars', '11 black cars', '1 yellow car', '1 silver car', '22 blue vans', '11 green cars', '11 black vans', '4 white cars']

split_list=[i.split(' ', 1) for i in mylist]

flat_list = []
for sublist in split_list:
    flat_list.extend(sublist)

dict= {flat_list[i+1]: int(flat_list[i]) for i in range(0, len(flat_list), 2)}
print(dict)
```

**[Result]:**

> ```
> dict={
> 'red cars': 8,
> 'blue cars': 3, 
> 'black cars': 11, 
> 'yellow car': 1, 
> 'silver car': 1, 
> 'blue vans': 22, 
> 'green cars': 11, 
> 'black vans': 11, 
> 'white cars': 4
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you, how would i edit this so the number was now the value not the key?

Comment: I have edited the answer, using int(flat_list[i]) to convert number from a string value to a digit key

Comment: it's still printing the number first?

Comment: Thanks @Dsmith97, now i Edit the code with the number as VALUE, and the STRING as a KEY.